# Insufficient privileges to complete the operation while update via azure graph api

Tags: php, azure, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to update users profiles in azure via graph api. When it comes to "mobile" attribute I receive the exception: "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation". Many attributes like city, streetAddress or telephoneNumber are updated successfully with the same portion of PHP code. Is this a configuration/schema problem?

Answer (score 0):

In my test, I promoted the permissions of the app accessing to WAAD, as the figures show:

[image]
and 
[image]

And I sign on the application with an account as an administrator  of organization,shown in the **USERS**=>**{user_name}**=>**PROFILE**=>**ROLE** section.

[image]

Then I can update user profile with mobile phone with any format. If the mobile phone number should be with country code, the number format should better be like ***`+1 1234567890`***.

BTW, in my test, after configuring the permission of application, I waited for almost an hour since Azure AD seemed to cache the old permission.